# Is it possible to insert checkboxes in Excel worksheet using Office.js API for Excel 2016?

Tags: office-js

Is it possible to insert checkboxes or other controls to a defined range of cells in Excel worksheet using Office.js API for Excel 2016? I was not able to find any reference about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI control on the canvas/range is not supported in the JavaScript model. I know it is not the same - but you could try to get the selected range (event) and show controls on the taskpane. We're working on adding the data validation API, which may also be a way to receive true/false response from the user.