# Excel ActiveX checkbox

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I´m looking for insert in a cell dynamically a checkbox button using the new Js-Addin, is that a way to do it? I check the documentation but it doesn't see to be possible, is that another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417941/is-it-possible-to-insert-checkboxes-in-excel-worksheet-using-office-js-api-for-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. You're right, we don't support it currently. You can ask a new feature request to do it. For feature requests please go to Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum and see if your feature has already been requested or request a new feature there.